# Validate aggregate query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I hope someone can explain me why I'm having this issue: I want to validate an ES (in version 7.4) query before launch it, every thing works fine if the query has no *aggs* clause but, if the query has *aggs*, ES says it's a no valid query, what is driving my crazy is the query works fine in ES but at the same time ES tells me it's not a valid query.

I think is because ES do not validate queries with *aggs* but I would love to "be sure", I've read the documentation and I found no clue.

Thanks a lot.

This is an example of ES query I want to validate

````
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "probe_id": {
                                "query": "probe id"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "agg_by_hours": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "hours",
                    "size": 24,
                    "order": {
                        "_term": "desc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [validate query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-validate.html) only supports the `query` section not the `aggs` section. Nothing else, not even `_source`, `sort`, `from` and `size`. You can also see this in the [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/RestActions.java#L252-L261).

If you add `?explain=true` to your URL, you'll see an explanation like:

```
{
  "valid" : false,
  "error" : "org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException: request does not support [aggs]"
}
```

So you can definitely validate your query but only take the `query` part and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Val for your answer and pointing me the source code, I appreciate it